# How to get MongoDB entries in date range including limits?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core

In a Mongo DB, I have the below entries:

```
> db.DomainObjects.find()
// [...]
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6..3"), "lev" : 7, "date" : ISODate("2021-02-01T00:00:00Z"), "val" : 29.1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6..4"), "lev" : 7, "date" : ISODate("2021-02-02T00:00:00Z"), "val" : 20.3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6..5"), "lev" : 7, "date" : ISODate("2021-02-05T00:00:00Z"), "val" : 15.8 }
// [...]
```

In a ASP.NET Core Service class, I have a reference to the collection using the Mongo DB driver with the below version installed:

[image]

Here is how the reference is created:

```
    public DomainService(IDomainDatabaseSettings settings)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
        _repo = database.GetCollection<Domain>(settings.DomainCollectionName);
    }
```

Then I'd like to get the entries by `DateTime` range (**including the limits**) using the following method:

```
public List<Domain> Get(int lev, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo) {
    Expression<Func<Domain, bool>> expr = entry => (entry.lev == lev)                    && 
                                                   (entry.date.CompareTo(dateFrom) >= 0) && 
                                                   (entry.date.CompareTo(dateTo) <= 0);
    return _repo.Find(expr).ToList();
```

I use the following GET request:

```
https://localhost:45645/api/DomainObjects/7/?dateFrom=2021-02-01&dateTo=2021-02-02
```

However, I only get the entries starting and including the lower limit, the entry on the upper limit is excluded.

For completeness, the controller is this:

```
    [HttpGet("{lev:int}")]
    public ActionResult<List<Domain>> Get(int lev, [FromQuery] DateTime? dateFrom = null, [FromQuery] DateTime? dateTo = null) {
        if (!dateFrom.HasValue) {
            dateFrom = DateTime.MinValue;
            return _domainService.Get(lev, (DateTime) dateFrom, (DateTime) dateTo);
        }
        if (!dateTo.HasValue) {
            dateTo = DateTime.Today;
            return _domainService.Get(lev, (DateTime) dateFrom, (DateTime) dateTo);
        }
        return _domainService.Get(lev, (DateTime) dateFrom, (DateTime) dateTo);
    }
```

If the lower limit `dateFrom` is omitted in the request, it should start with the earliest entry, if the limit `dateTo` is omitted, it should return all values from `dateFrom` up until and including today.

Comment: Use $gte and $lte operators.

Comment: The date is stored in MongoDB as _UTC datetime_ (your program might be using some other format).